# Cascade delete limits?

Tags: cascadedelete, delete

Is there a limit to the number of records that can be deleted in cascading delete?

We are receiving an error "Deletion Unsuccessful You cannot delete this object" when trying to delete records involved in master detail and lookup cascade delete relationships.

It is my understanding their are limits on delete() functions in Apex, but is there delete limits in the declarative delete functionality?

Comment: Have you checked if any of the objects in your cascade have references from any other objects?

Comment: Yes, there are references from other objects. But it seems to allow delete on "small" amount of records and "error" on larger amounts of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Considerations for Relationships](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_considerations.htm) in the Salesforce Help:

> In a many-to-many relationship, a user can't delete a parent record if
>   there are more than 200 junction object records associated with it and
>   if the junction object has a roll-up summary field that rolls up to
>   the other parent. To delete this object, manually delete junction
>   object records until the count is fewer than 200.

It may be that the records you're deleting are falling under this limitation.

Comment: We spoke to Partner Support about this and confirmed. According to support, the rule stated above applies to junctions with or without roll-up summary fields. Did not get a clear answer about why the documentation specifically includes the Roll-up summary criteria. Do you have any insight into this? Thanks!

Comment: Asking the product owner and writers -- please hold...